# python cloud app on windows azure

Tags: python, azure

Hello i am an absolute beginner on cloud computing and on python. I would like to start develope a password manager app to Azure using Python. Please can you advice me some tools to start with my project? (which Apps - frameworks to use)

Comment: I don't agree w/closing this question, as the Windows Azure SDK for python, and python developer hub, were just released in June 2012. Not many people know about the SDK, developer hub, and related tutorials yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python apps, in general, run in Windows Azure as they would run anywhere else, as they'd be running in Web or Worker roles (which are basically Windows Server 2008 R2 or SP2 VMs) or Virtual Machines (which are Windows Server or Linux images you manage). You just need to provide the python sdk and supporting libraries for your app.

Having said that: Windows Azure has a python sdk to interact with Windows Azure's services (today this covers Service Bus and Storage, a subset of Windows Azure services). When installing the Windows Azure sdk, you'll also get python 2.7 installed. You can get the installer in the python Develop portal for python, [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/). In this portal, you'll also find a few tutorials for working with python in Windows Azure.

If you want to see the source of the Windows Azure SDK for Python, it's available on github, [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python).

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you believe that is ok to create my password manager app with python Django + mysql and then to upload them to Windows Azure or it is better to use other tools?

Comment: Azure+Django+MySQL tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django-and-mysql/

Comment: Not being a Django expert, I really can't provide guidance there. If you are comfortable with python and related tools such as Django, I think you should build your app with the same tools you'd use on a local server. You still need to think about security and other aspects that you'd always worry about (e.g. securing stored passwords vs. storing in the clear).

Comment: The Django tutorials on the Azure site have dangerous practices. They use GET for forms and stick unvalidated data into databases. Don't use their tutorials as anything resembling what you do in real projects!